# logic- translating quantification in english

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, logic-translation

> Let Q(X) be the statement "x has developed a program in JAVA" and P(x) be a statement "x spends more than four hours surfing the internet" where the domain for x consists of the students in ICS.
>
> Q1.) $∀x~P(x)$

A1.) For every x, x spends more than four hours surfing the internet.

> Q2.) $∃x~¬Q(x)$

A2.) There is an x such that x has developed a program in JAVA is false.

> Q3.) $∀x~(P(X)\to Q(X))$

A3.) For every x, x spends more than four hours surfing the internet then x has developed a program in JAVA.

Are my answers to this correct?

Comment: More "English": 1) Every student in ICS spends more than four hours surfing the Internet.

Comment: ohh i understand now. thank you, so my answer is wrong :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a bad start, but you need to translate completely, rather than mix math symbols and words.   You should talk about students in ICS rather than $x$.

Also you should try for more natural speech , without losing the intent of the sentence.

$\forall x~T(x)$ "Every student in ICS drinks tea."

$\exists x~\neg B(x)$ "Some student in ICS does not eat biscuits."

$\forall x~(T(x)\to B(x))$ "Every student in ICS, who drinks tea, does eat biscuits."

And such.

Comment: thank you so much for your help :) i really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

1. It sounds nicer if you eliminate the variable: "All ICS students spend more than 4 hrs surfing"
2. Idem + ambiguous subclause + get rid of the technical word false: "There is an ICS student who hasn't developed a Java program
3. Eliminate variable + missing if: "All ICS students who spend more than 4 hrs surfing have developed a Java program"

Comment: but do you think my answer is wrong? or is it still technically right?

Comment: I think 1 is strictly right, 2 is ambiguous and 3 is strictly wrong for the reason stated.

Answer (score 0):

While your answers are correct, you are probably supposed to use a "more natural" language. For example:

1. Every student in ICS spends more than 4 hours surfing the internet.
2. Some student in ICS hasn't developed a JAVA program.
3. Every student in ICS that spends more than 4 hours surfing the internet has developed a JAVA program.

Comment: are you saying all of my answers are technically correct? even though the huge difference in my answers, and yours?

Comment: @JaneDoe Yes, that's what I'm saying.  (But you may want to say more explicitly that all your $x$'ses are students in ICS.)

Comment: I hope my teacher thinks the same way. I'd be really bummed if i got it wrong since he just surprised us with this test. Sure do hope, he considers.